# Getting error message when run react-native application on Xcode 10.0

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, xcode10

I am new for IOS application development I am trying to run react native application on MAC (Virtual box) but stuck after launch screen.

Getting error at this line of code.
[image]

showing below message on report navigator.

2018-09-26 05:03:23.637243+0530 Leaderboard[56620:700325]  - [I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2018-09-26 05:03:24.334073+0530 Leaderboard[56620:699937] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2018-09-26 05:03:25.352 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:216] Initializing  (parent: , executor: (null))
2018-09-26 05:03:25.385767+0530 Leaderboard[56620:699937] Initializing  (parent: , executor: (null))
2018-09-26 05:03:25.749 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:293] Running application Leaderboard ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2018-09-26 05:03:25.831679+0530 Leaderboard[56620:699937] Running application Leaderboard ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2018-09-26 05:03:26.353502+0530 Leaderboard[56620:699937] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001052a91e6 **exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010371e031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010531e975 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Leaderboard                         0x0000000101e80451 +[FIRApp configure] + 481
    4   Leaderboard                         0x0000000101e7fb07 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 871
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000107ee96fb -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 278
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000107eeb172 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4123
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107ef05cb -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1677
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001082b2f7e __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 866
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000108685a39 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001082b2bba -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001082b33db -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 675
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000108c24614 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 299
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000108c244ae -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010890875d __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 221
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000108b034b7 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000108908627 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 223
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001086850e0 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000107eeeeac -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001084c1bcb -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e05a2f3 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 331
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e062cfa __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 225
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010695a7ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010695fdb8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
    24  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e08e470 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24
    25  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e08e12e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 439
    26  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e08e68e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010524bbb1 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001052304af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010522fa6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010522f30b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010d42ea73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    32  UIKit                               0x0000000107ef2057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    33  Leaderboard                         0x0000000101e7fc90 main + 112
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a98c955 start + 1
    35  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Firebase in your project, you should create an app from Firebase console and configure it. Then you should download `GoogleService-Info.plist` and copy to your project. You can clearly see this on your error logs.

Please follow this tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: I will check it, actually the same project was working on Xcode 9.4 it stop working after upgraded to Xcode 10.0

Comment: This this was related to GoogleService-Info.plist, actually this file was already there but not working on Xcode 10, I have created new file(GoogleService-Info.plist) on Xcode and updated content. Thanks for your help!